# Graph to show changes over time

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data with BMI and HTN in 3 time points, where BMI is continuous and HTN is categorical. I should show the changes for BMI and HTN over these three times by a graph like  line graph (continuous values for BMI and numbers for HTN). Is there any way to do it in R? and Could I have both graphs in one figure?  Thanks.

| ID | BMI_1 | BMI_2 | BMI_3 | HTN_1 | HTN_2 | HTN_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 35 | 37 | 40 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A2 | 29 | 32 | 35 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| A3 | 38 | 39 | 42 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A4 | 33 | 34 | 34 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: I am not sure how you want to show the graph.  is it in a single plot or multiple?

Answer (score 1):

We could reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and use `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'), 
        names_sep = "_") %>% 
    mutate(grp = as.integer(grp)) %>%
    ggplot() + 
     geom_line(aes(x = grp, y = BMI, group = ID, color = ID)) + 
     geom_line(aes(x = grp, y = HTN, group = ID, color = ID)) +
     theme_bw()
```

---

If we want two plots, can use `facet_wrap`

```
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>% 
   separate(name, into = c('name', 'grp'), convert = TRUE) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = value, color = ID, group = ID)) + 
     geom_line() + 
     facet_wrap(~ name) + 
     theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

`scales` can be modified in `facet_wrap`

```
  ...
  facet_wrap(~ name, scales = 'free_y') + 
  ...
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), BMI_1 = c(35L, 
29L, 38L, 33L), BMI_2 = c(37L, 32L, 39L, 34L), BMI_3 = c(40L, 
35L, 42L, 34L), HTN_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), HTN_2 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), HTN_3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to show one line as a mean for BMI and one line for HTN which shows the number of people with 1 and number of people with 0. Do you have any idea on that?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  summarise(across(-ID, mean)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("stat", "time"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, value, group = stat)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~stat, scales = "free_y") +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]

Or perhaps:

```
df1 %>%
  summarise(across(-ID, mean)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("stat", "time"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = stat, values_from = value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(BMI, HTN, label = time)) + 
  geom_path()  +
  geom_label()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I ran your code on my data and got this error: "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

Comment: Perhaps your version of the data is grouped? I get no error using @akrun's `df1` code.    [This is a good example of why it's best practice to share your example input data as explicit code so that the data object we use is an exact copy of yours.]

Comment: I removed NA from data and it fixed the issue. Thanks.